# Is Absolute positioning a best practice or should I avoid it?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am watching the ASP.NET learn video on http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-13.aspx
and it is showing you can place controls on a page using Absolute positioning.  I am just wondering if this is a best practice or should I avoid Absolute positioning?  It seems like a nice, easy feature, but there must be some reason why it is not selected by default in the VS IDE.

Comment: It's a worst practice - that must be why it is used so often (and because it's simpler).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many users change the font size of your page by configuring their browser settings. If you use absolute positioning, things will not align right for them.

In absolute positioning, when your page gets more complex, a single design decision would require you to reposition all of the elements, but in relative positioning, you would only need to change one value, and all the other elements would adjust accordingly.

Comment: +1 I agree, although this doesn't mean absolute positioning has no use at all - see my answer

Comment: I think you mean 'static' positioning would adjust elements accordingly. Relative positioning would place everything in normal flow first, then move elements out of place.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute positioning takes the element out of the flow of the document. This means that it will no longer align with other elements. There are very good reasons to do this sometimes but generally you want to avoid it.

ASP.NET is notorious for using bad HTML/CSS practices. This framework is designed for 'rapid development' not 'elegant, web standards development.

Comment: While this is correct to some degree, you're misrepresenting how absolute positioning works. Since its absolute RELATIVE to its positioned parent, it certainly can still line up with other elements. You need to be careful, certainly, but it is very useful, and well supported across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to be suspicious :)

Basically, don't use it for controls.

I only use it for dialogs, or other features which I can calculate the correct position relative to the page size.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is more about css than the visual studio. Because of the reasons explained in other answers, you should use relative positioning where possible.

This doesn't mean absolute positioning has no use at all. Check out http://csszengarden.com/, to see how you can use a simple html structure and still use some really interesting designs.