# Div appears above of scrollbar

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar, footer

Hello guys i'm building a website with wordpress, and i've got a little problem with internet explorer 7

you can see a screenshot of the error here http://d.pr/U3LX as you see the #footer div is above the scrollbar, i've tried something but i can't just figure it out.

This is the footer css http://pastebin.com/nuxhXXSe

If you prefer a live preview go here with ie7 http://d.pr/1UHi

Edit : i've noticed now that this error appears on every other browser (chrome, firefox etc...)

How do i fix this ? Any advice ?

Comment: Don't have your footer as an element within your main content page. The scroll bar is part of the element (it's not the browser scroll bar) and your fixed position footer quite rightly sits atop it.

Answer (score 1):

Im thinking the same. Because in my browser, the header sits above the scroll bar as well. Do you have a Div wrapping around all of your content? If your using wordpress, im sure you have a header.php and a footer.php. Im assuming the div would open in header.php, and close at the very end of footer.php

you want your footer div inside of that div

Answer (score 1):

you can change the position for `#footer` from `fixed` to `absolute` then you can set `top:1100px;` or whatever is better for your.

Answer (score 1):

even though I don't agree on the markup overall but, it seems that you have set the footer width = 100% **PLUS** padding-left = 15px!! which will always takes the full browser width (because of width:100%) AND 15px more! (this is not visible just because you are using overflow: hidden, but it's there!)
Try removing the left padding and apply it on inner element.

**EDIT**: after checking on IE, the above is not the cause of this but still indeed a bad practice..

Comment: yeah thanks for your comment, today was a tiring day, which made me nervous too, and I did not notice the errors, now i've fixed them...

what's wrong with the markup in this page ?

Comment: I've never used (or seen) the approach you are using as the way to go...check this [article](http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/) the thing is, position absolute should not be for page structure as it removes the element from the page normal flow, more reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687938/is-absolute-positioning-a-best-practice-or-should-i-avoid-it)