# CSS position text depending on text-width

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to achieve this design

[image]

I have the following markup and it **cannot** be changed:

```
<button>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="/icon/path"></use>
  </svg>
  <p class="text">Viewing</p>
</button>
```

The css to achieve this is as follows:

```
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: -4em;
}
```

But if the text changes length it leads to this:

[image]

I tried using `calc` and `transform` as well as changing `position:absolute` to `relative` but nothing works. Is this not possible with CSS?

Comment: use right instead of left and make sure you have position:relative on button

Comment: Can be done with JQuery o only with with CSS?

Comment: Sorry I added the class, it's on the text.

Comment: Make button relative, make icon absolute and put it on the right, add padding-right to `.text` so the icon never overlaps

Answer (score 1):

Make button relative, make icon absolute and put it on the right, add padding-right to .text so the icon never overlaps

See the space on the right, that would be your svg icon (green). You would need to adjust the spacing to the icon's actual spacing, the code below is just to show you the approach to take

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  background: green;
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.text {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="/icon/path"></use>
  </svg>
  <p class="text">Viewing</p>
</button>

<button>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="/icon/path"></use>
  </svg>
  <p class="text">Viffdewingsdfsdfasfdfsa</p>
</button>
```

Comment: Position absolute should be avoided because not all browser show them correctly.

Comment: @klediooo Which browser won't show this simple css properly?

Comment: As long the users don't change their font-size it ll worked i guess. Otherwise IF they do they will have problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687938/is-absolute-positioning-a-best-practice-or-should-i-avoid-it

Comment: That's not going to be an issue, absolute positioning is used everywhere. I have also vertically centered the icon so even if the font is bigger, the icon will center. Besides, the user can do a lot of things to make things not work but that doesn't mean you shouldn't use it. I can disable js on my browser because I am paranoid and 99% of the sites online won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use margin-left for the svg-tag.

As well im wondering how the css should affect something because you don't even have a class 'text' in your html. So maybe this could a problem too. :)

Comment: Then try to use margin-left instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
svg {
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    background: green;
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
}

.text {      
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <p class="text">Viewing</p>
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="/icon/path"></use>
    </svg>
</button>

<button>
    <p class="text">Viffdewingsdfsdfasfdfsa</p>
    <svg>
        <use xlink:href="/icon/path"></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

About absolute position, he position itself with the first element that has the relative position set.
If you set button with relative position, when you set top, right, left or bottom. He will look the button for set itself position if not he look at the screen.

Because of this, he ran over your element, he is out page flow.