# position: Absolute ( or fixed ) layout vs normal layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a strange question I always wanted to ask.
I was wondering of the advantage/disadvantage to have a div layout with only position:absolute rather than a traditional one.
I looks simpler to code and you can achieve the the same results ( if all divs are aligned properly ).
Why would you prefer to use a traditional layout?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is pretty subjective. Nonetheless, here's my two cents.

#### Positioned Layout

- Pro: *Arguably* more intuitive code.
- Con: Everything is outside of the normal document flow. Making segments of the page that are dynamic, i.e. content, very difficult to position around.

#### Normal Layout

- Pro: Just the opposite - document follows normal flow. Making it easier and requiring less code for a majority of your layout.
- Con: Typically you have to mess with `float`, `margin`, or `position` to achieve segments like a sidebar.

In the end, I typically develop a normal layout as my base. I save the positioned items for things that will **never** move, i.e. a top right navigation, temporary UI elements, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

@louis; From my point of view use `position:absolute;` for a hole layout is not good. there are several reasons.

1)`absolute position` div not consider height & width which when means you resize your page then the elements are overlapping each other. Which mesh the page.

2)suppose you have `vertical divs` with same `class` like `panel` . Then if you give them

```
.panel{
position:absolute;
top:20px;
}
```

then what happens  all divs take `top:20px;` from top of page & overlapping each other. Absolute position
made everything is outside of the normal flow of layout.

**for more check this link**

[Is it considered bad practice to use absolute positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning)