# CSS Browser Selectors

Tags: css, positioning, absolute

In laying out a page with absolute positioning, I realized that it rendered differently from browser to browser.  I've been looking online about css selectors to see if there was some way to change the positioning based on which browser the user was using, but I haven't been able to find anything very helpful.  Any ideas?

Comment: is there any particular reason you're using absolute positioning? This should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @Oliver Why do you feel absolute positioning is bad?

Comment: I'm using absolute positioning for a table which appears on an image which is overlaid on the main page as a pop-up.

Comment: Pages are rendered differently across browsers, put up with it. In your specific case, it makes sense that you provide minimal testcase example (e.g. via jsfiddle.net).

Comment: You're likely doing something wrong to cause the different rendering between browsers. Changing `top` and `left` depending on which browser is being used sounds like exactly the *wrong* solution.

Comment: You're right.  I found my mistake.  In creating the table, I failed to set a default cellpadding cellspacing value, so each browser handled it differently.  After fixing it, it worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry haven't logged in for a while. I think this post says it better than I could. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bad strategy to me... I wouldn't want to switch from absolute to, say, relative or some other kind of positioning based on the kind of browser. They all should implement positioning fairly similar. You'd probably need to add some extra styles to make a particular element behave properly on certain browser, but changing the global positioning method based on browser is not a good idea, IMO.

**UPDATE:**

On CSS alone, there isn't any standard mechanism to detect a browser. You can use tricks like the one below to detect a particular version of IE, for example:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

or something like:

```
<!--[if gte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For a more complete list of options [see here.](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml)

Another alternative is to use jQuery (if it's an option for you) and adjust the element's style using javascript depending on the browser. Something like:

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
    $("#div ul li").css( "display","inline" );
 } else {
    $("#div ul li").css( "display","inline-table" );
 }
```

More [examples here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

A word of caution: none of the above methods is infallible. One, for example, can make Firefox identify itself as Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm not thinking of changing from absolute to relative.  I'm just trying to change the top, left positions based upon the browser they are using.

Comment: @user1281231 updated my answer now that you clarified what you meant by changing the positioning.