# Asp.net css stop div from expanding page height

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, xhtml

So the problem is that I am trying to design a XHTML page in ASP.NET and the current approach that I take keeps expanding the page size when I simply want to fit the control within the `div`.

I am using Relative in most divs as I've read about using absolute being bad practice. Hopefully this is an easy fix, here is some of the type of code that I tend to write. Note that after 4 or 5 of these controls the page will start expanding in height even though there is still plenty of space around the screen at 900+px.

The example below uses an image button, but this happens with all other controls also. If I add 4-5 of these as mentioned it will start expanding the page which im trying to stop.

```
<div class = "MyHeader">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="MyHeaderBTN" runat="server" Height="33" Width= "95" ImageUrl="~/Images/anyURL.png" onmouseover="this.src='/Images/anyURLHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/anyURL.png'"/>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS class

```
.MyHeader
{
    height: 35px;
    left: 160px;
    position: relative;
    top: -116px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**Edit**: Hopefully this clears it up (sorry I don't know how to use JSfiddle).
Ultimately what I am trying to do is stop the web page height from increasing whenever I add any new divs. So without(or only a few) I get wanted page and after adding a few divs the page will increase in size leaving more empty space at the bottom.

Comment: I feel the question is not very clear. Can you please create a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) with the problem and give the link?

Comment: In Style/site.css , there should be a class: ".main" . Try to set a max-height property for it, to value you want. But I need to add, I don't think absolute is that bad.. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to JohnyTee's recommendation of changing Max-Height in main as well as reducing Min-Height I was able to stop the page expanding and I seem to be able to continue adding relative items.

Thanks