# Arranging and positioning two divs below each other in CSS

Tags: css, html, position, positioning

I'm new to CSS, so this question might be dead simple. I am laying out a website and am stuck with positioning.

On the site, I have a middle section in which there is a header with some scrollable content underneath. Here's the relevant CSS for the header div:

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Now, I simply want the content div to immediately follow underneath, and can't figure out how to do that.

```
position: relative; 
top: 0;
```

doesn't seem to work (which I initially expected to). Both divs are on the same logical level and wrapped inside the middle section div. I am probably missing something extremely obvious and easy.

Comment: Is there any reason that your `#header` is absolutely positioned? Remove that style and I think you'll find the `<div>`s will stack how you're expecting.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning for tips on which positioning style to use.

Comment: Thank you F4r-20, this worked perfectly. Thank you everyone for the tips. Mainly, I think I needed to understand the crucial principle about relative positioning.

Answer (score 4):

If you have something like

```
<header>header</header>
<main>main content</main>
```

Use this css:

```
header, main
{
    display: block; /* because <main/> is very new */
    padding: 20px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}

header
{
    background: blue;
}
```

That's all, because block elements go below each other per default.

http://jsfiddle.net/86wX4/

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that your `#header` is absolutely positioned? Remove that style and I think you'll find the `<div>`s will stack how you're expecting.

Giving the `<div>` an absolute positioning takes it out the flow of the page, so elements that are still in the flow, *'don't think'* it's there, hence, they don't stack on top of each other.

Say this is your markup:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

If you are going to absolutely position these elements you'll want to arrange them using `left`, `top`, `right` and/or `bottom` styles. I.E:

```
#header{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:50px; //Because the header is 50px high
}
```

**BUT**

Positioning all of these relatively (or leaving them at the default, static) would stack them how you want them anyway - and they would even stretch the width of the page for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason to use your header div with absolute position? you can use relative position for both div's to arrange below each other.