# How to select only one child element in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a box with a header, a first paragraph, and a second paragraph. How can I select only the last paragraph in CSS so I can move it down, so it isn't overlapping the first paragraph? This is the code I have:

```
#info-box > p {
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: #979797;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

#info-box:nth-child(2) {
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    color: #979797;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning to begin with?

Comment: You also probably shouldn't be using :nth-child on an ID as it implies that you are probably using the same ID on more than one element. Just use a class and select it that way.

Comment: umm...I'm not sure why I was using absolute positioning. I just deleted that line and it fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

Quoting [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo):

> The `:last-child` pseudo-class represents an element that is the last child of some other element.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/d5kG7/):

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    border:solid;
    margin:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-width:1px;
}
div:last-child{
    background-color:white;
}
```

Although to be fair, absolute position is rarely "the way" like Nit implied in the comments. Fixed sizes in pixel don't work too well on different screen sizes and different zooms, prefer a more logical layout. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186044/1348195) on why.

Answer (score 0):

CSS for last element try to use `:last-child`

```
#info-box:last-child {
}
```

Check here for reference CSS selector
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: It is generally better to cite [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) rather than W3Schools. w3schools are in no way affiliated with the w3c (although they like it when people think that. They're [generally not a good resource](http://w3fools.com).