# Image overlapping in div focus

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to make a div move when another div is clicked.

Here is a jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vufosn18/ (make sure you make it fullscreen so the image doesn't overlap with the text)

I have been googling around for a bit and can't find anything, so I tried:

```
#feas:focus #construct{
    margin-top: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

When I click on feasibility it gives construction management a margin-top of 300px.

Any help is appreciated, if your answer could be in JavaScript/CSS that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be hard to fix all your issues in one answer. But I'll try to get you going:

- Everything is absolute, I think this is not recommended for your case. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning)
- You are using ID's everywhere, causing lots of duplicate styles. Try changing this to classes. This will be much easier to manage small changes.
- I recommend checking that you are working [html strict](https://validator.w3.org/), this may prevent having rare situations in different browsers. (FYI)

#### To answer your question:

There are a lot of plugins out there that are easy to use. I suggest you to use one of them instead:

- https://jqueryui.com/accordion/
- [A step by step example](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-accordion/) (just googled it)
- ..

For what you want to show in each tab you can have independent html/css. By default is img and p relative. So they won't overlap then.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple animation

Click on hello and the div with the word world will move down

```js
function click(){
document.getElementById('bottom').style.top="50px"
}
document.getElementById('top').addEventListener('click',click,false)
```

```css
#top{
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border:solid;


}
#bottom{
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border:solid;
  transition-property:top;
  transition-duration:3s;

}
```

```html
<div id="top">
hello
</div>
<div id="bottom">
world
</div>
```