# CSS formatting - put text in top left corner

Tags: css

I have a blank webpage with the word test on it. Rather than being exactly in the top left corner it is away from the corner. What CSS will put it back in the corner?

Comment: It's not only `TEST` text inside, is full of divs and layouts from wordpress. However this should be closed as offtopic. Good luck

Comment: position absolutely.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Worst man, seriously, didn't expect that from you.

Comment: I didn't check the website but from OP text I suggested that. What's wrong with me?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Positioning is bad man.

Comment: Why positioning bad? We need positioning for some sorts of layout (we can't do without it). Seriously it may differ that I didn't check the site.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Not related to any site, but generally speaking, yea, position is bad. 100s of reasons. Google it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning

Comment: I disagree. How do you position the element outside the container then?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal This is not about positioning outside the container, it is just to find why. Kindly target the problem, don't do hackjob. :)

Comment: The links outside stackoverflow I cannot open. And did you check the quentin's answer in your linked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the **WordPress theme** doing all things:

1. The `body .grid-container` has a `max-width`. Remove it.
2. The `.separate-containers .site-main` has `margin`s. Remove it.
3. The `.separate-containers .inside-article` has `padding`. Remove it.

So your CSS should have these extra, if you wish to get rid of the theme's styles:

```css
body .grid-container {max-width: none;}
.separate-containers .site-main {margin: 0;}
.separate-containers .inside-article {padding: 0;}
```

**For only one post, i.e., the homepage you shown**

If you want this to be displayed for only one post, then you can add the post id as a class name. You can find the post id here:

```
<body class="page <strong>page-id-266</strong> ...
```

So taking that `page-id-266` class, we have:

```css
body.page-id-266 .grid-container {max-width: none;}
.page-id-266 .separate-containers .site-main {margin: 0;}
.page-id-266 .separate-containers .inside-article {padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Hey that worked, however it changed all of my pages. Is it possible to have it apply to just that one page? I tried putting it inside .page-id-266 {} but didn't work. many thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: @kev002 Yes. Get the post id from the body tag and add it.

Comment: Thanks, done. Would you be able to modify the code to show how to do that.

Comment: @kev002 See the update. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. For the individual page it doesn't go all the way in the corner for some reason. It does move slightly left though.

Comment: @kev002 Show the page, lemme see what needs to be done. `:)`