# how to position two boxes to make them align well?

Tags: css

I want to put the both h1 and inner box to the upper left corner of the outer box.

Here is my attempt, but failed. I am looking for a javascript free solution.

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h1>
some text
</h1>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong the `position:absolute`. In your case, to make your code work, change from `position:absolute` to `position:relative` in `.outer`.

When you tell an element to use `postion:absolute`, it will bring that element out of the DOM, and it will looking for the nearest parent which has `position:relative`.

**Note:** I don't know why you are using `position` in this example, because this is the last option I will take if I need to align these elements, you can play around with `display:inline-block` or `display:flex` to make your elements align correctly!

Comment: I like you explanation on the use of  `position:absolute`.

Comment: thanks, if you want to see more details about position, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position or from css tricks is a very good reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Answer (score 2):

Use `absolute` instead of `relative` positioning.

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 20px;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <h1>
some text
</h1>
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if there is a margin on outer box.

Comment: @ZhenyangHua, What do you want it to do if there is a margin on the outer box?

Comment: align both h1 and inner box to the topleft corner of the outer box (not window).

Comment: @ZhenyangHua Well, this solutions does work. You had a typo in `.outer`. You misspelled `position: absolute`. Try to fix that, I'm sure it will work.

Comment: This relies heavily on explicit positions and heights/widths.

Comment: @GSaunders, Very true. It is the code of the OP though. I can't really change that, can I?

Comment: You can improve it, and just let them know what changes you made and how it improves the code or how it's a better practice. :)

Comment: @GSaunders Why is using absolute positioning bad practice? You should [read some answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning).

Comment: In the case of your example, the code would break if other elements were around it because there's no relative parent to contain the absolute children. In this case, if the outer was position relative, you could just use absolute on the inner, and the h1 could go inside the inner. Less code and more reliable. take a look at my answer for an example.

Comment: @GSaunders I can tell. If OP wants an absolute positioned element, who am I to tell him different? He does know the use case, you and I do **not**. This is an answer to his question, not a code review based on assumptions of whether or not absolute positioning is the right fit for the use case. Your answer is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use relative positioning for the outer box, and absolute for the inner box. For the h1, make sure it's inside the inner box and then you can use padding instead of explicit widths and heights.

https://jsfiddle.net/hnezfs3k/1/

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>
      some text
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>



.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.inner {
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```