# log in webpage -> <div> and comparing user input

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am trying to create a simple log in webpage. But my page is not being rendered as I expect it to be.

Here is my code:

```js
function logIn(username, password){
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if(username == "a" && password == "a"){
        window.location.href="awesomePage.html";
    }else{
        alert("Incorrect username or password!");
    }
}
```

```css
#user {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
}
#pass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 7.5px;
}
#username {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 40px;
}
#password {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
}
#logIn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:logIn(username, password);" method="post">
  <div id="user"> Username: </div>
  <div id="username"> 
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username here." /> 
  </div>
  <div id="pass"> Password: </div>
  <div id="password"> 
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here." /> 
  </div>
  <div id="logIn"> 
    <input type="button" value="Log In" onClick="javascript:logIn(username, password);"/> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Before, when I typed **a** for username and **a** for password and I clicked **log in** I got the alert message: **Incorrect username or password**.

[image]

I tried changing the HTML to (other code remains the same):

```
<div id="un"> <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username here." /> </div>
<div id="pw"> <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here." /> </div>
```

And therefore changing the CSS to (other code remains the same):

```
#un {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 40px;
}
#pw {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

When I type **a** for username and **a** for password it takes me to **awesomePage.html**, but the input fields are positioned where I don't want them to be.

[image]

**My question is: How do I fix this?**

Also, another small question: Should I name other pages I have: **awesomePage.html** or **awesome_page.html**, or is **Awesome Page.html** just fine?

Comment: You are aware that this is not a real login ... everyone can just go look up the "credentials" in the JavaScript code.

Comment: -Avoid using `position: absolute ` use `position: relative` instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning
and also, avoid using `ids`, use `classes` instead:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-use-id-instead-of-class

Comment: Your css style should not affect your code, can you create a fiddle or code snippet for that?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I am aware. I know you should compare it with strings from text files and also hashing or something like that. I just wanted to make a test.

Comment: @anfuca I get the same problem with classes.

Comment: Change ID's in your markup, id must be unique, you can't have multiple id's, that's main problem here. The code is working fine.

Comment: @nevermind Did you see the writing that I changed it? If you did, I don't understand what you meant by your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to solve your problem with minimum changes in code:
I have just did a small change in the css and another small change in the html IDs, which keep everything looks the same and functional.
For sure you can improve this a lot by not depending on positions as previous answers listed.

```js
function logIn(){
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    debugger;
    if(username == "a" && password == "a"){
        window.location.href="awesomePage.html";
    }else{
        alert("Incorrect username or password!");
    }
}
```

```css
#user {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
}
#pass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 7.5px;
}
#username-ctr, #username {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 40px;
}
#password-ctr, #password {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
}
#logIn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:logIn(username, password);" method="post">
  <div id="user"> Username: </div>
  <div id="username-ctr"> 
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username here." /> 
  </div>
  <div id="pass"> Password: </div>
  <div id="password-ctr"> 
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password here." /> 
  </div>
  <div id="logIn"> 
    <input type="button" value="Log In" onClick="logIn()"/> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer to your second question:
It depends on many factors, but you can find many SEO recommendations and best practices if you google "website page naming convention",  my recommendations:
- Don't use spaces in page names.
- Don't use _ , as I know some search engines count this as a normal character not a separator, use - instead.
- Be consistent with all other website pages naming convention for better user experience.

Comment: This works. It's just I saw it too late, I already fixed it. I just doubled the values for **#un** and **#pw**. Also, later I replaced the **<div>** with **classes**.

Comment: What about the question I asked at the end?

Comment: @S.A. thank you, I have added the answer to your second part of the question to my answer above, hope it help.

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, this is not a real login, but if you want to use it your problem is that you are using repeated ids on "div" and "input". After changing them to #un and #pw you need to also update your css:

```
   #username, #un {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 40px;
   }
   #password, #pw {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your JavaScript code like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function logIn(){
  
    var username = document.querySelector("input[id='username']").value;
    var password = document.querySelector("input[id='password']").value;
  
    if(username == "a" && password == "a"){
        window.location.href="awesomePage.html";
    }else{
        alert("Incorrect username or password!");
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to iterate again, please don't ever write production code like this, as this is not a real login and nothing is preventing anyone from inspecting your page source and they will then be able to see what your username and password is.

To fix your layout issue you will need to add both the child and parent elements to your CSS styling since you are using absolute positioning

```
#un, #username {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 40px;
}
#pw, #password {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

I also want to explain what went wrong with your initial code as it might help someone else understand why you changed the element ids.

Firstly in your JavaScript function you are expecting parameters for username and password, but neither are used in your code example which makes passing them in completely redundant, and you can remove them as from the function definition, you are using document.getElementById to obtain both the username and the password anyway.

When you run your code and log the output of the username and password values you will notice that they both return as undefined. The reason for this is that you have duplicate id values in your HTML source, so it is actually trying to obtain the value from another element (in this case it is identifying the parent div elements instead of the input elements).

```
  <div id="username"> 
    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username here." /> 
  </div>
```

The fix for this would be to just make sure your id values are unique by changing the input id to "username_input" or the parent id to "username_container" and then alter your function to account for the modified id values.

Next issue, in your HTML code you are calling your function twice in the form, and although this won't really cause issues here, once you start doing asynchronous requests there might be issues with duplicate requests, etc.

```
<form action="javascript:logIn(username, password);" method="post">
```

(this is actually not called because you don't have a submit button elsewhere in your form)

and

```
<input type="button" value="Log In" onClick="javascript:logIn(username, password);"/>
```

You don't need an action or method in your form element, so you can really choose one or the other.

So here is a CodePen link with the amended code in which I made the modifications:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbxOOP

And to answer your additional question. When naming HTML pages that will be called directly from the browser, always prefer to use snake case (ie. awesome_page.html) or a hyphen (awesome-page.html). Reason for this is that in some setups the OS might not be case sensitive when looking for the file, so if you have awesomePage.html and awesomepage.html, it will be unpredictable which file it will actually return. Never use spaces in the file names.