# How do I change my css so my different divs do not overlap when having different resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**The problem is that my divs are shown correctly as long as my browser is in full screen, but when I scale down the resolution the divs overlap, how do I get a relative positioning to each other**

```
#curve_temp {
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 30px;
margin-right: 100px;
}
#curve_vibr {
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
right: 220px;
}

#curve_laut {
position: absolute;
top: 600px;
left: 30px;
padding-right: 100px;
}

#curve_rpm {
position: absolute;
top: 600px;
right: 220px;
}

#curve_quali {
position: absolute;
top: 900px;
left: 30px;
padding-right: 100px;
}


            <div class="user-dashboard">
                <h1>Hallo, User!</h1>
                <div id="logo_eg">
                <center><img src="logo.png" alt="engineguru_logo" class="our_logo" width="476" height="191"></center></div>
                <div id="curve_quali" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
                <div id="curve_rpm" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
                <div id="curve_laut" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
                <div id="curve_temp" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
                <div id="curve_vibr" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
                <div id="flaticon"><a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/home" title="home icons">Home icons created by Freepik - Flaticon</a></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick. I would use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to set the desired screen size breakpoints. Additionally, it may help to use `rem` or `em` or `%` instead of `px` as those help with responsive design in screen size scaling.

You could set the css styles to be between two widths, for example with a tablet:

```
@media (min-width: 475px) and (max-width: 768px)
{
     /* Insert screen size styles for these breakpoints here. */
}
```

Or use settings that specify styles upto a specific screen size dimension:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px)
/* For mobile phones: */
{
/* Insert screen size styles for these breakpoints here. */
}
```

With your code shared above, it could look something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){
/* For mobile phones: */

   /* Adjust values to the appropriate px dimension. */
   #curve_temp {
     position: absolute;
     top: 300px;
     left: 30px;
     margin-right: 100px;
  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
/* For tablet screens: */
    
       /* Adjust values to the appropriate px dimension. */
       #curve_temp {
         position: absolute;
         top: 300px;
         left: 30px;
         margin-right: 100px;
      }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px){
/* For desktop screen: */
       
       /* Adjust values to the appropriate px dimension. */

       #curve_temp {
       position: absolute;
       top: 300px;
       left: 30px;
       margin-right: 100px;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @takeGin were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using absolute positioning is far more rigid and makes it difficult to write layouts that respond well to changing content. [more infos here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186044/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-absolute-positioning#:%7E:text=Using%20absolute%20positioning%20is%20far,They%27re%20simply%20too%20explicit.)
You can use flexbox, put the divs you want to respond correctly in a flex-container as follows.
html:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    /*put your divs here*/
</div>
```

css:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

You can get the design you want with [these flexbox properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in addition to spacing manipulation.
A better way to give multiple divs the same style is giving them the same class and styling it with css.
Your old code:

```
<div id="curve_quali" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
      <div id="curve_rpm" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
      <div id="curve_laut" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
      <div id="curve_temp" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
      <div id="curve_vibr" style="width: 535px; height: 268px; vertical-align: right" ></div>
```

better way to code:

```
<div id="curve_quali" class="class_name" ></div>
<div id="curve_rpm" class="class_name"</div>
<div id="curve_laut" class="class_name"</div>
<div id="curve_temp" class="class_name"</div>
<div id="curve_vibr" class="class_name"</div>
```

you rewrite the same style you gave in your style attribute as follows:

```
.class_name {
/* your styling over here */
}
```